# Can I use non trivially copyable iterator in parallel version of std::find_if?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a simple code which just find any divider of my own `BigInt` type, which have own random access iterator:

```
  BigIntRangeIterator range(2, x);
  auto i = std::find_if(std::execution::par, range.begin(), range.end()
              , [&](auto y) {return x % y == 0;}
  );
```

My iterator contains `std::vector`, so it is not trivially copyable. When I try to compile this code, I get error from `std::atomic` implementation:

```
/usr/include/c++/9/atomic:191: error: static assertion failed: std::atomic requires a trivially copyable type
  191 |       static_assert(__is_trivially_copyable(_Tp),
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Does it mean, that only trivially copyable iterators can be used in parallel version of `std::find_if` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it needs to use `std::atomic` to avoid data race, while primary template of `std::atomic` requires the class to be trivially copy constructible.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic#Primary_template

Comment: But where does the standard says that an iterator should be trivially copyable?

Comment: @Evg The standard cannot specify that, i deem, considering the freestanding implementation. Plus, execution policies are unspecified. So I think the compiler may use `std::atomic` to prevent data race, and the error message proved that.

Comment: If an implementation requires more than the standard, I would say such an implementation is not conforming to the standard.

Comment: @Evg +1. But 1. I deduced that from the error message 2. The standard says executions are unspecified. I mean the standard doesn't require `std::atomic` because freestanding implementation **may** forbid the using of multithreading thus theres's no need to use atomic. However, after doing further research, I found cppreference says that it's programmers' duty to prevent data race when using execution. So maybe requiring `std::atomic` does more than expected, in summary, I can only answer the question now but cannot tell the exact reason behing it.

Comment: @JohnDing, but such hardcoding of `std::atomic` in std library makes executions unusable in some cases. Maybe library should to provide some ways to use own synchronization mechanisms instead of hardcoded atomic? The similar problem I met is hardcoded `size_t` in std library for iterators difference, which makes no sense for big numbers iterator difference types.

Comment: @Shadasviar as you mentioned, something like `std::ptrdiff_t` is also implementation-defined. So maybe it's simply the compilers don't want to consider extreme situations which will make us write extra code for ordinary uses. Simply a guess, I'm personally not so sure about this, to be honest.

Comment: @Shadasviar, could you give a particular example for `size_t`?

Comment: @Evg, in question code, one of errors on my `gcc 9` is: `/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:137: error: switch quantity not an integer
  137 |       switch (__last - __first)
      |       ^~~~~~` which is assumed that difference type is integer. After some searching std code I found that difference type is just alias for size_t in some places, i will find it in some time

Comment: @Evg, if replace `find_if` with `none_of`, then I get error: ```/usr/include/tbb/blocked_range.h:78: error: invalid cast from type ‘BigInt’ to type ‘tbb::blocked_range<BigIntRangeIterator>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’}
   78 |         return size_type(my_end-my_begin);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~```, where `size_type` is just `size_t` typedef

Comment: But actually it is tbb implementation, not std

Comment: @Shadasviar, thanks. I don't think there is a simple solution to all these problems.